# Dynamically pull values from nested form using Gravity Forms & Gravity Wiz Nested Forms

Tags: wordpress, nested-forms, elementor, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

So I've been going through a restructure build of an entire site, and part of that involved switching from Formidable Forms to Gravity Forms. We did this because we wanted to use the Nested Form feature, so that we could automate multiple attendees without having to create a new form for each.

Here's the problem - on our old site that did have a separate form per attendee via Formidable, we had a code using the Canvas API to send name + email info to Canvas and automatically register users for the online courses this company offers. In trying to convert sections of this code to work with my nested forms, I'm running into a snag:

1. The main issue is that the value is being spit out as all of the information from the nested form entry, not by name/ email/ etc.
2. The info is being spit out twice, perhaps because of the way the forms are structured? There are a couple calculations happening in the forms/ nested forms so I'm chalking it up to that.

```
      [1] => WC_Meta_Data Object
        (
            [current_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 212
                    [key] => Attendee Registration
                    [value] => 
    
                                            
                                            Name
                        Test Name
                                            Email Address
                        courses@email.com
                                            Cell Phone
                        (333) 333-3333
                                            Would you like to receive text message reminders for this registration?
                        No
                                            Post-class notification is required for the following states, please identify if you will be using this class to fulfill any state license requirements:
                        N/A
                                            You'll receive a hard copy and digital certificate upon course completion. Additional options are available here:
                        
                                            All live classes include a hard copy manual and regulations. To join our effort to save paper, please also add any of the following options to take your books home:
                        
                    
                


                )

            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 212
                    [key] => Attendee Registration
                    [value] => 
    
                                            
                                            Name
                        Test Name
                                            Email Address
                        courses@email.com
                                            Cell Phone
                        (333) 333-3333
                                            Would you like to receive text message reminders for this registration?
                        No
                                            Post-class notification is required for the following states, please identify if you will be using this class to fulfill any state license requirements:
                        N/A
                                            You'll receive a hard copy and digital certificate upon course completion. Additional options are available here:
                        
                                            All live classes include a hard copy manual and regulations. To join our effort to save paper, please also add any of the following options to take your books home:
                        
                    
                


                )

        )
```

Also: I was playing around with grabbing the ID of the main entry via [_gravity_form_linked_entry_id], and grabbing the nested info from that via [_gravity_form_lead].

The best I was able to get from that was this... so yeah kind of lost on how to progress here if anyone has any pointers! Thanks so much!

```
[data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 211
                    [key] => _gravity_forms_history
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [_gravity_form_cart_item_key] => 72201a9586fb30895b8fb5cac2a796b9
                            [_gravity_form_linked_entry_id] => 125
                            [_gravity_form_lead] => Array
                                (
                                    [form_id] => 1
                                    [source_url] => https://chcv2.flywheelstaging.com/product/air-monitoring-specialist-live/
                                    [ip] => 75.151.95.41
                                    [42.1] => Course Price
                                    [42.2] => $580.00
                                    [42.3] => 1
                                    [21] => 122
                                    [40.1] => Add-On Fees
                                    [40.2] => $0.00
                                    [40.3] => 1
                                )

                            [_gravity_form_data] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [bulk_id] => 0
                                    [display_title] => 
                                    [display_description] => 
                                    [disable_woocommerce_price] => no
                                    [price_before] => 
                                    [price_after] => 
                                    [disable_calculations] => no
                                    [disable_label_subtotal] => yes
                                    [disable_label_options] => yes
                                    [disable_label_total] => no
                                    [disable_anchor] => no
                                    [label_subtotal] => Course Fee
                                    [label_options] => Additional Attendees + Selected Options
                                    [label_total] => Attendee Registration + Add-Ons:
                                    [use_ajax] => no
                                    [enable_cart_edit] => no
                                    [enable_cart_edit_remove] => no
                                    [keep_cart_entries] => no
                                    [send_notifications] => no
                                    [enable_cart_quantity_management] => stock
                                    [cart_quantity_field] => 
                                    [update_payment_details] => yes
                                    [display_totals_location] => after
                                    [structured_data_override] => no
                                    [structured_data_low_price] => 
                                    [structured_data_high_price] => 
                                    [structured_data_override_type] => overwrite
                                )

                        )

                )
```

**Update:** Here's how I've incorporated the code from Rochelle's comment below, where I'm getting an error

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'canvas_enroll', 20, 2 );

function canvas_enroll($orders) {
    $query = new WC_Order_Query( array(
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'return' => 'ids',
    ) );
    $orders = $query->get_orders();
    foreach($orders as $order){
        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data) {
            if(isset($item_data->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_lead"]["form_id"]) && !empty($item_data->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_lead"]["form_id"])){ 
                $linked_entry=$item_data->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_linked_entry_id"];
                $entry_id = $linked_entry;
                $entry = GFAPI::get_entry( $entry_id );//id of Parent Gravity Form
                if(isset($item_data->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_lead"]['2']) && !empty($item_data->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_lead"]['2'])){
                    $linked_nested_value=$item_data->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_lead"]['2'];
                    $nested_value_array = preg_split ("/\,/", $linked_nested_value); //array of child entries
                    $child_entry_amt = substr_count($linked_nested_value, ",") + 1;
                    if ($child_entry_amt > 0){   
                        for ($n = 0; $n < $child_entry_amt; $n++) {
                            $entry_id_nest[$n]=$nested_value_array[$n];
                            $entry_nest[$n] = GFAPI::get_entry( $entry_id_nest[$n] ); //nested form entry
                            $name[$n]  = $entry_nest[$n]['12.3'].''.$entry_nest[$n]['12.6'];//replace 1.3 and 1.6 with nested field id of name
                            $email[$n] = $entry_nest[$n]['11']; //2 is the GF nested field id of email        
                        }
                    }
                }            
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure what I'm looking at but I think I've done something similar.  Is this a woocommerce product with a Gravity Form Add-on?  Am I just looking at a var_dump of the woocommerce meta data?

Comment: Hey Rochelle, that's exactly what you're looking at! And it is a WC product with a GF add-on. The tricky part here is that there is also a nested forms add-on, and I'm unable to grab specific fields from the nested form within the GF form.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got this figured out! Something that was super helpful was to echo the item meta data ($value, in my case) for that to display all the ids and such, that's how I was able to figure out that I needed 21 in that ID for the child entries.

I'm not really sure why I had to switch to wc_get_order instead of wc_order_query, but it solved the errors I was getting.

```
function canvas_enroll($order_id) {

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id);
    
$order_id = array(
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'return' => 'ids',
);  
    
if(!empty($order) && isset($order)){
// Loop through order line items
foreach( $order->get_items() as $key => $value ){

    // get order item data (in an unprotected array)
             
            if(isset($value->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_lead"]["form_id"]) && !empty($value->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_lead"]["form_id"])){ 
                
                $linked_entry=$value->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_linked_entry_id"];
                $entry_id = $linked_entry;
                $entry = GFAPI::get_entry( $entry_id );//id of Parent Gravity Form              
                
                if(isset($value->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_lead"]['21']) && !empty($value->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_lead"]['21'])) { //21 was the id for my child form

                    
                    $linked_nested_value = $value->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_lead"]['21']; 
                    
                    $nested_value_array = preg_split ("/\,/", $linked_nested_value); //array of child entries
                    $child_entry_amt = substr_count($linked_nested_value, ",") + 1;
                    if ($child_entry_amt > 0){   
                        for ($n = 0; $n < $child_entry_amt; $n++) {
                            $entry_id_nest[$n]=$nested_value_array[$n];
                            $entry_nest[$n] = GFAPI::get_entry( $entry_id_nest[$n] ); //nested form entry
                            $firstname[$n]  = $entry_nest[$n]['12.3'];//replace 12.3 with nested field id of first name
                            $lastname[$n]  = $entry_nest[$n]['12.6'];//replace 12.6 with nested field id of last name
                            $email[$n] = $entry_nest[$n]['11']; //replace 11 with nested field id of email        
                        }
                    } 
                } 
            }         
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to paste the code I used for another project that I needed to pull the same type of data in case it puts you on the right track.  You'd have to replace the numbers with the ids from your forms:

```
$query = new WC_Order_Query( array(
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'return' => 'ids',
) );
$orders = $query->get_orders();
foreach($orders as $order){
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data) {
        if(isset($item_data->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_lead"]["form_id"]) && !empty($item_data->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_lead"]["form_id"])){ 
            $linked_entry=$item_data->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_linked_entry_id"];
            $entry_id = $linked_entry;
            $entry = GFAPI::get_entry( $entry_id );//id of Parent Gravity Form
            if(isset($item_data->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_lead"]['2']) && !empty($item_data->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_lead"]['2'])){
                $linked_nested_value=$item_data->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_lead"]['2'];
                $nested_value_array = preg_split ("/\,/", $linked_nested_value); //array of child entries
                $child_entry_amt = substr_count($linked_nested_value, ",") + 1;
                if ($child_entry_amt > 0){   
                    for ($n = 0; $n < $child_entry_amt; $n++) {
                        $entry_id_nest[$n]=$nested_value_array[$n];
                        $entry_nest[$n] = GFAPI::get_entry( $entry_id_nest[$n] ); //nested form entry
                        $name[$n]  = $entry_nest[$n]['1.3'].''.$entry_nest[$n]['1.6'];//replace 1.3 and 1.6 with nested field id of name
                        $email[$n] = $entry_nest[$n]['2']; //2 is the GF nested field id of email        
                    }
                }
            }            
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That looks awesome, excited to give it a shot tomorrow

Comment: Keep me posted.

Comment: Hey so I'm actually getting an error when I use this - the kind where the page loads but kinda wonky and it says "There has been a critical error on this website".

Edit: Hit enter way too soon haha, whoops! I'll add what have in there as an edit to my original post.

Comment: Yes, feel free to post exactly what you have added as this is intended to run inside a function. (Do you have access to your error logs on the site?). You'll have to make some adjustments to make this work either way but I will quickly scan for errors.  In the meantime, you probably need to run var_dump on things like '$linked_entry' to really see what it returns to see if you can grab the nested form entry values.

Comment: I added it to my initial post as an update :) 

I just googled how to look at the error logs (can you tell I usually do front end yet haha) so I will take a look at that next time I'm in there! Thanks!

Comment: Ha! I get it.  Do you have access to the host/server?

Comment: I do have access to the host, and I can FTP in, but I'm not sure if I access to the actual server

Comment: Who ever you host with should be able to give you some info about how to access your error logs.

Comment: Hey @Rochelle ! Had to change up the order of tasks on this project so actually just getting back to this issue. Looks like I'm getting an ajax error for some reason: 14/Jan/2022:17:49:23 +0000 "POST chcv2.flywheelstaging.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200 /www/.wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php - - 3943.512 107520 23.08%

If it's helpful, I've been giving it a random message to echo to see where it stops working - there seems to be some issue with this line?:      
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data) {

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Try this first to see if it changes anything:

```
$query = new WC_Order_Query( array(
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'return' => 'ids',
) );
$orders = $query->get_orders();
foreach($orders as $order){
  if(!empty($order) && isset($order)){
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data) {
        if(isset($item_data->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_lead"]["form_id"]) && !empty($item_data->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_lead"]["form_id"])){ 
            $linked_entry=$item_data->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_linked_entry_id"];
            $entry_id = $linked_entry;
            $entry = GFAPI::get_entry( $entry_id );//id of Parent Gravity Form
            if(isset($item_data->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_lead"]['2']) && !empty($item_data->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_lead"]['2'])){
                $linked_nested_value=$item_data->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_lead"]['2'];
                $nested_value_array = preg_split ("/\,/", $linked_nested_value); //array of child entries
                $child_entry_amt = substr_count($linked_nested_value, ",") + 1;
                if ($child_entry_amt > 0){   
                    for ($n = 0; $n < $child_entry_amt; $n++) {
                        $entry_id_nest[$n]=$nested_value_array[$n];
                        $entry_nest[$n] = GFAPI::get_entry( $entry_id_nest[$n] ); //nested form entry
                        $name[$n]  = $entry_nest[$n]['1.3'].''.$entry_nest[$n]['1.6'];//replace 1.3 and 1.6 with nested field id of name
                        $email[$n] = $entry_nest[$n]['2']; //2 is the GF nested field id of email        
                    }
                }
            }            
        }               
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response! No change yet, I did initially get a 500 error instead, but then I got the same ajax error. Here's that 500 error:
14/Jan/2022:19:59:38 +0000 "GET chcv2.flywheelstaging.com/checkout/order-received/44412/?key=wc_order_mpui2IjBpHYTq" 500 /www/index.php - - 1752.138 142336 54.22%


To be clear because this could be a mistake on my end, does this work for the function that's being wrapped around your snippet?

function canvas_enroll($orders)